# Macro string Interpolation / How to unquote inside string?

Tags: hy

I have a macro like:

```
(defmacro test [x] `"~x")
```

After running it expands to the following:

```
=> (test abc)
'~x'
```

Why doesn't it expand to `'abc'`?

What is the correct method to unquote inside a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused why you expected this to work, and I'm unclear what you want. `~` in your example is in a string literal, so it's an ordinary string character, not the `~` operator, the same way that `((fn [x] "x") 5)` returns `"x"` and not `"5"`.

If you want to stringify the model that you're passing into a macro, use `str`, like this:

```
hy 1.0a1+114.g2abb33b1 using CPython(default) 3.8.6 on Linux
=> (defmacro test [x] (str x))
<function test at 0x7fe0476144c0>
=> (test abc)
"abc"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a more general question here: **how can I use string interpolation at macro-expansion time?**

The answer is to remember that the unquote prefix `~` can be applied to *any form*, not just bare symbols, and that it is simply shorthand for `unquote`.

So you can just use an f-string, and unquote the f-string. Using the original example:

```clj
(defmacro test [x]
  (quasiquote (unquote f"{x}")))
```

Or using the shorthand prefix symbols:

```clj
(defmacro test [x]
  `~f"{x}")
```

`~f"{module} ..."` is valid shorthand for `(unquote f"{module} ...").

As another example of using arbitrary forms with `~`, you could use `str.format` instead of an f-string:

```clj
(defmacro test [x]
  `~(.format "{}" x))
```

---

As a real-world example, here is a macro I wrote today:

```clj
(import sys
  typing [NoReturn])

(defn ^NoReturn die [^int status ^str message]
  (print message :file sys.stderr)
  (sys.exit status))

(defmacro try-import [module]
  `(try
     (import ~module)
     (except [ImportError]
       (die 1 ~f"{module} is not available, exiting."))))
```